# CMS written in Java or PHP that allow export as static HTML pages

Tags: java, php, html, content-management-system, export

I am looking for a CMS that allows me to export the site as static HTML (i.e. the site must be able to work without the CMS itself). I want to be able to create the site on my PC and then upload the exported static HTML to a hosting server.

I must mention that I do not want to use site downloaders to "pull out" the content from a CMS, I want an option in the CMS itself, something like "Export as static content", "Export as HTML" etc.

So far I found Alfresco for Java and Typo3 for PHP but there are so many of CMS tools out there... :(

Can someone share from his experience and point to a good CMS which generates static HTML?

Thank you all!

Comment: Maybe this question is more apropriate on the webapps site, it's not really programming related, http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check out Wordpress, I think it had an export option that was quite good. Or possibly good ole Google docs?

Answer (score 0):

[WebJaxe](http://media4.obspm.fr/outils/webjaxe/en/) does that. Actually, it's not even an export: websites created with WebJaxe are always static.

Answer (score 0):

Don't look to recreate the wheel inside a CMS. Choose a CMS because it solves business problems you're facing. To generate a static copy of a site use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/).

So long as you're not doing dynamic JavaScript library loading or css @import declarations, wget is going to grab everything you need and set it up in the correct relatively pathed directory structure so you can stand it up statically somewhere else. Just understand things that are *dynamic*, like search, **will not work** no matter what solution you choose.

Comment: OP said he does not want a downloader/grabber/crawler

Comment: @ajreal - well aware of what he asked for. However, the better approach is what I've described.

Comment: @ajreal - static sites are a complex problem - consider the algorithm a CMS must use to do this properly. HTML files, images, CSS, JavaScript, embedded objects. Also dynamic URLs, (e.g. ?paramter=value&paramter=value etc...); these must be translated into a physical file and referenced correctly in the static copy's links. wget deals with all of these issues correctly and because it's crawling the links will capture even those things that the CMS may not be aware of.

Comment: find an example that copies an entire site and deals with dynamic URLs and I'll take you seriously. Your link does not address those issues.

Comment: @ajreal - so you have worked with Typo3 and know it can do an entire site, not just individual pages? And as far as crawlers are concerned, I'm referring specifically to wget, which does deal with duplication.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a static website generator like [PieCrust](http://bolt80.com/piecrust/). There is also a bunch of alternatives listed [here](http://bolt80.com/piecrust/doc/alternatives/).